# Condition on UInt64 field in WHERE clause in ClickHouse

Tags: clickhouse

In ClickHouse [Playground](https://play.clickhouse.tech/?file=playground) dataset conditions on UInt64 fields don't seem to work. For example query:

`SELECT * FROM hits_100m_obfuscated where WatchID = 8120543446287443000`

doesn't return anything (even though I copied the ID from the dataset). Same is true if the condition is on UserID. But the following works just fine:

`SELECT * FROM hits_100m_obfuscated where ClientIP = 3078276782`

I guess the reason is that ClientIP field has type UInt32, but both UserID and WatchID - UInt64. I tried to use toUInt64 and CAST, but didn't succeed.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think it's some weird bug with playground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
seems web/frontend issue

SELECT '- '||toString(max(WatchID))||' -', max(WatchID), toString(max(WatchID)) FROM hits_100m_obfuscated


- 9223372033328793741 - | 9223372033328794000   | 9223372033328794000
```

https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/10824

Comment: Thanks, Denis. Will try to install and run it with the client.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is a bug of Playground.

As a temporary workaround, you can send a direct request to service endpoint using the favorite HTTP API client such as Postman, Fiddler, curl etc:

```sh
curl "https://play.clickhouse.tech/api/v20.3/?database=datasets&user=playground&password=clickhouse&query=SELECT+*+FROM+hits_100m_obfuscated+where+WatchID=8927014313511165737+limit+1+format+Vertical"
```

---

[image]